# Thingsboard running on k8s

Tags: kubernetes, thingsboard

I am attempting to set up ThingsBoard on a google k8s cluster following the documentation [here](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/blob/release-2.3/k8s/README.md).

Everything is set up and running, but I can't seem to figure out which IP I should use to connect to the login page. None of the external ips I can find appear to be working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public access is set up using an Ingress here https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/blob/release-2.3/k8s/thingsboard.yml#L571-L607

By default I think GKE sets up ingress-gce which uses Google Cloud Load Balancer rules to implement the ingress system, so you would need to find the IP of your load balancer. That said the Ingree doesn't specify a hostname-based routing rule so it might not work well if you have other ingresses in play.